# ReactJs: My object renders before the constructor fetches data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

As a reactJs beginner I'm trying to write a simple single-page webapp. My intention is to fetch data from an API and show it on my web page, so I need to fetch URL's, pass them to my children objects, and have them fetch data again.

So apparently the rendering of the children start when the fetching of URL's is still happening.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          title: '',
          events: '',
          people: '',
      };
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    fetch('http://example.org/').then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({
      title: json.title,
      events: json.events,
      people: json.people,
    }))
  }

render(){
   return (
      <div>
          <Child
            url= {this.state.events}
          />
          <Child
            url= {this.state.people}
          />
    );
}
```

And this is one of the possible children:

```
class Child extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          collection: [],
      };
  }
    componentWillMount(){
      fetch(this.props.url, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
          },
        },
      ).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then( json => this.setState({
              collection: json[Object.keys(json)[0]],
          }));
      }
  });
}
```

These list are empty when trying to run the app. Remarkable is that, when hardcoded the same URL in the constructor (or the render of the parent), the construction will work perfectly.

So my question is, is there any way to make my render wait for my fetch to finish, or another way to work around this problem?

Comment: What is your question though?

Comment: How to make this work, without hardcoding URL's. Maybe I should specify it in the question, thanks

Comment: Fetch data in `componentWillUpdate`. Additionally check https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: @zerkms "Any state changes via this.setState are not allowed as this method should be strictly used to prepare for an upcoming update not trigger an update itself."
regarding the `componentWillUpdate`, taken from react docs

Comment: @radix yep, I should have mentioned `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: @bertcommeine you could also only render the child components when data is actually ready.. What happens is that the children try to fetch data in the componentWillMount before they actually have the data from the parent

Comment: @bertcommeine tell me one thing, you want to hold the rendering until you didn't get the data in child ? with current code when the data fetched successfully is it rendering or facing any issue in that?

Comment: @radix And how could I do that? Sorry, I'm a real beginner with react.

Comment: With the current code, the data won't get fetched correctly since it sends the request in the children before it gets the right URL. If I pass the URL myself instead (aka hardcode it) the data is fetched and used perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to fetch the data instead of `componentWillMount`.

2- To hold the `rendering` in child component, use a bool in parent component, it will tell you the status whether data has been fetched successfully or not.

Use this:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            events: '',
            people: '',
            isDataFetched: false
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://example.org/')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => this.setState({
              title: json.title,
              events: json.events,
              people: json.people,
              isDataFetched : true
          }))
    }

    render(){
        if(!this.state.isDataFetched) return null;
          return (
              <div>
                  <Child
                    url= {this.state.events}
                  />
                  <Child
                    url= {this.state.people}
                  />
              </div>
          );
    }
}
```

> Why your code is not working?

`componentWillMount` method get called only once before the rendering, you are doing the api call in parent component and the fetch api in child component dependent on the data of that fetch call, and before the parent fetch call fetched the data, child component get rendered and `componentWillMount` of child component get called, because of that the fetch call in child component is not working.